# I can't able to copy folder when i create NET USER using powershell script simultaneously

Tags: powershell

I can't able to copy folder from adminuser to Created NET USER's desktop(not public desktop) before first sign in.

Comment: Please describe more clear, what you want to achive, what you tried so far and what your error messages are. This includes writing a question.

Answer (score 0):

- The new users profile (including the Desktop) doesn't exist before the
  first login.
- With the first login the template (default) is copied to the new
  profile.